# Extracting the first 3 bits of an uint8

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

A struct I'm dealing with has a field defined as `uint8_t`. The spec also states that all multiple-byte fields are represented in host-endian format.

Bits 0:3 contain the information that I need (also an unsigned integer). Using plain C, how do I extract those 3 bits and convert it to a number type?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unit8_t a;
unit8_t b;

a = input data;

b = a & 0x0F;       // b contains a number from 0 to 15